# starting another activity from SpeechRecognition service in android?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, voice

[image]I am working on android application, which recognize the voice and convert the voice into text as a background process, it is working fine yet, but my next step is to open different built-in activities like message, gallery, email camera through intents,
my code is

```
public void onResults(Bundle b) {
            ArrayList<String> as = b
                    .getStringArrayList(sr.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            String res = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < as.size(); i++) {
                Log.e("OnResult", as.get(i));
                res += as.get(i);

            }
            if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("message")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplication().startActivity(i);
            }


        }
```

I am getting exception at this :( 
Anyone help, I would appreciate , peace,

Comment: What exception exactly? Remember to always provide exception text and stacktrace.

Comment: I have added the picture above,

Comment: It's better to paste text instead of picture. The picture is not complete. You missed few important lines above.